# How to prevent mermaid flow charts overflowing in quarto

Tags: r, pdf, flowchart, mermaid, quarto

I am trying to create a flow chart in mermaid but the image is overflowing.

Edit 1: here is the code I used (it's a .qmd document)

````
---
title: "Workflow"
authors: "Satya P"
format: pdf
---

```{mermaid}
%%| fig-height: 9

flowchart TB
1(Available Data)

1 --> 2(aaaaaaaaa)

1 --> 3(bbbbbbbbbb)
1 --> 4(cccccccccc)
1 --> 5(ddddddddddd)
1 --> 7(eeeeeeeeee)
1 --> 8(fffffffffff)
1 --> 9(ggggggggggg)

7 --> 10(hhhhhhhhh)
8 --> 10(hhhhhhhhh)
9 --> 10(hhhhhhhhh)


3 --> 11(iiiiiiiii)
4 --> 11(iiiiiiiii)
5 --> 11(iiiiiiiii)

10 --> 12(jjjjjjjjj)
11 --> 12(jjjjjjjjj)

12 --> |kkkkkkkkk| 13(lllllllll)

13 --> |"mmmmmmmmmmm"| 14(nnnnnnnnnnn)

14 --> 15(oooooooooo)
2 -.-> 15
```
````

and here is the result I am getting

[image]

how can i customize this in quarto? As you can see i need this in pdf format.
ps: please ignore the text

Comment: Add the code for the mermaid diagram with your question and also the YAML section of your document so that we can reproduce the mermaid chart.

Comment: I can't reproduce the clipping; even when doubling the text length of node 2 everything looks fine, the figure is appropriately scaled. You could try a line break in node 2 using `</br>`.

Comment: I did reproduce the crop part at the bottom and open an issue to track 
https://github.com/quarto-dev/quarto-cli/issues/2438

Thanks for the report